# Excel VBA to derive or transform a new table based on inputs in other table

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to determine a VBA solution for transforming a user input table in to a machine readable table.  I reviewed a number of VBA and Excel table threads but couldn't locate something that fit the bill.

Briefly, we manage a number of promotions in areas that only last for a number of months.  The users want to provide the following table:

```
PROMOTION | REGION  | STATE    | FirstMonth | LastMonth
VERGO     | MIDWEST | ILLINOIS | 1/31/14    | 3/31/15
```

And want to receive this table back with them after we perform a lookup on Region/State/Month to determine the fee for a given month.  After it's reviewed, it's provided to our Finance partners to help with the budget.

```
DATE    | PROMOTION | REGION  | STATE    | FEE
1/31/14 | VERGO     | MIDWEST | ILLINOIS | 100
2/28/14 | VERGO     | MIDWEST | ILLINOIS | 100
3/31/14 | VERGO     | MIDWEST | ILLINOIS | 100
4/30/14 | VERGO     | MIDWEST | ILLINOIS | 120
5/31/14 | VERGO     | MIDWEST | ILLINOIS | 120
...ECT
5/31/15 | VERGO     | MIDWEST | ILLINOIS | 175
```

I'm struggling to find some logic I could employ that would first read a row from the initial table and then copy/paste that row X number of times based on how many months lapse between the First and Last month of the promotion.

Any pointers on where to go with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would loop through datarows in Worksheet1 and therein loop from FirstMonth to LastMonth and write the data to Worksheet2:

```
Sub createMonthlyTable()
 Set oWs1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
 Set oWs2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

 lStartrowWs1 = 2
 lLastrowWs1 = oWs1.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row

 lRowWs2 = 2

 For i = lStartrowWs1 To lLastrowWs1
  With oWs1
   sPromotion = .Cells(i, 1).Value
   sRegion = .Cells(i, 2).Value
   sState = .Cells(i, 3).Value
   dFirstMonth = .Cells(i, 4).Value
   dLastMonth = .Cells(i, 5).Value
   dMonth = dFirstMonth
   Do While dMonth <= dLastMonth
    With oWs2
     .Cells(lRowWs2, 1).Value = dMonth
     .Cells(lRowWs2, 2).Value = sPromotion
     .Cells(lRowWs2, 3).Value = sRegion
     .Cells(lRowWs2, 4).Value = sState
     dMonth = DateSerial(Year(dMonth), Month(dMonth) + 2, 1) - 1
     lRowWs2 = lRowWs2 + 1
    End With
   Loop
  End With
 Next
End Sub
```

Greetings

Axel